# How to find cell in a column that contains a string and return value of a cell in another of row?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

If the cell contains `"external"` from the `C` column then copy cell `"good"` from the `D` column, into the `E` column, in the rows where the `A` column contains `003`.

Below are two images (before and after) in excel.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

I tried to find a correct script but it did not work out. It needs to be changed to "row" and "column" where I put "???" :

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb_source = openpyxl.load_workbook("path/file.xlsx")
sheet = wb_source['Sheet1']
x=sheet.max_row
y=sheet.max_column

for r in range(1, x+1) :
   for j in range(1, y+1):
       copy(sheet.cell(row= ???, column=???)
         if str(copy.value)=="external":
         sheet.??
         break
wb_source.save("path/file2.xlsx")
```

How should they be added (row and column)?

Comment: Why does the cell `E3` in your example have the value `"good"`? According to your explanation, only rows that have `"external"` in their `C` columns should have a value copied over. Also, specifically of they also have `003` in their `A` column, but we can also see that you're doing the same on other `A`-column values.

Comment: @HampusLarsson - I'm sorry for the mistake of expression. Because in `A` column there are two that contain the same number (`003` and `003`). A person can be external and internal. I want to return the values from `C` column to `E` column for both types (`internal` and `external`) where there is the same number. Which will have to return the values in two rows, not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read the entire sheet.
2. Create a dictionary for the external products
3. Write back to Excel.

Try:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("file1.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']

data = list()
for r, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows()):
    data.append([cell.value for c, cell in enumerate(row)])
mapper = {l[0]: l[-1] for l in data if l[2]=="external"}

for r, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows()):
    if ws.cell(r+1, 1).value in mapper:
        ws.cell(r+1, 5).value = mapper[ws.cell(r+1, 1).value]
wb.save("file2.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you for writing a script. It is almost solved, but I have to return the values on two rows (as seen in the second image) where there is the same number (i.e. `A3` and `A4` , `A5` and `A8` , `A9` and `A11`)